# Binding to LDAP using SSL keeps failing - Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Our script continues to fail whenever attempting to bind to LDAP (active directory) using SSL, I am stumped.  We can successfully connect using the unsecured method, but we are attempting to perform password changes which requires SSL.  Our script snippets are as follows:

config.php

```
// SSL

 $LDAPDOMAIN="dc=campus,dc=local";
 $LDAPLOCALDOMAIN="campus.local";
 $LDAPHOST='ldaps://localhost';
 $LDAPPORT=636;
 $ldap = ldap_connect($LDAPHOST, $LDAPPORT) or die ('<p class="message">Error connecting');

 ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
 ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```

reset.php (uses config.php)

```
if ($ldap)  {

  $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap,$username."@".$LDAPLOCALDOMAIN,$password);
  if (!($bind)) {
    @ldap_close($ldap);
    die ('<p class="message">Your password is incorrect, please try again 
      <a href=javascript:history.back()>click here</a><br>');
  }
```

Whatever we do, the script "dies" in reset.php.  When we were using regular LDAP, we at least could communicate.  Our config.php code was as follows:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect($LDAPHOST) or die ('<p class="message">Error connecting to LDAP');
```

I appreciate any assistance and thank you ahead of time.

Update*

I tried running the following simple program to test my LDAP.  SSL still does not work, however regular LDAP does.  Is this a configuration issue?  My certificates should be okay, I created a new one and enrolled my server.  I've used an LDAP utility which binds and connects just fine.  Just not PHP though.

```
<?php
    $ldap = ldap_connect("ldaps://localhost/");
    $username="USER@campus.uhsa.local";
    $password="password";

    if($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $username,$password ))
    echo "logged in";
    else
        echo "fail";
        echo "<br/>done";
        ?>
```

My result is Fail.

Comment: What error code are you receiving? Are you using an SSL cert you created?

Comment: Yes we just created/enrolled a new certificate.
For some reason when attempting to output the php error with "die (ldap_error($ldap));" instead of what I have above ("password is incorrect"), I receive:

Warning: ldap_error(): 2 is not a valid ldap link resource in C:\inetpub\hosts\ADPasswordReset\passreset.php on line 50.

Comment: have you tried to connect (ldapsearch or whatever) from the command-line to determine if php is really the base problem?

Comment: I've used an ldap utility to test binding and connection to SSL.  I decided to try and simply connect using a small program.  Again regular LDAP worked but SSL does not.  My certificates should be okay.  I updated my initial question with the code I just tried running.

Comment: are you running the ldap server locally? If so turn up debugging on the ldap server and check for errors. This sounds like a ldap server configuration problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try running `ldapsearch` and giving us the error output? It would look something like this:

```
ldapsearch -x -d 1 -LLL -H ldaps://localhost -b 'dc=campus,dc=local' -D 'username' -W '(sAMAccountName=username)'
```

where the parameters are:

- -x: forces the connection to use simple authentication instead of SASL (emulating the PHP ldap_bind() function)
- -d 1: show debugging output, increase the number for more verbosity
- -LLL: changes the output format to remove some LDIF information you don't need for debugging
- -H: the host URI specifier; you can change this to "ldap://" to test non-SSL binding
- -b: the bind DN
- -D: the bind credential username, CN, or other identifying string
- -W: forces `ldapsearch` to ask for a password

If you were using SASL to connect to an Active Directory server over LDAPS, it'd be necessary to set the "[maxssf](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.1/html/Configuration_and_Command_Reference/Configuration_Command_File_Reference-Command_Line_Utilities-ldapsearch.html#tab.Description_of_the_GSSAPI_SASL_mechanism)" parameter to zero. I'm not exactly sure how PHP's LDAP functions work, so it might be worth trying to set that parameter if you can figure out how.